# How do I find the max age from a csv file and then return that person's name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The title pretty much sums up my issue. Here's the code I've got so far:

```
def oldest_player(): #what is the name of the oldest player?
    for i in player_data:
        row_idx = player_data.index(i)
        age_list = []
        zero_age = 0
        if cell(row_idx, "Age") > zero_age:
            if cell(row_idx, "Age") > age_list[0]:
                curr_age = cell(row_idx, "Age")
                age_list.clear()
                age_list.append(curr_age)
            else:
                continue
        return age_list

oldest_player()
```

**More or less, I'm asking how to find the max value of a column in a csv file, and then how to return a name that corresponds with that data entry.**

Thank you!

EDIT:
Here is a picture of the data that "player_data" is referring to:

[player_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQzQH.png)

Comment: What is player_data?

Comment: Should've provided more context. It is a csv file; player_data is the list of all the data.

Comment: could you show the format of player_data?

Comment: I just posted a picture at the bottom of the post that will show the first few entries of the file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```py
max_player = sorted(player_data, key=lambda c : x[2])
```